# Twilio: Can Sip be used to call a Twilio Conference?

Tags: twilio, sip, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I've been reviewing the Twilio Voice documentation, but I can't see if it would be possible for a sip communications infrastructure to join a Twilio Conference.

This would be the ideal scenario for us.

However, if this wasn't possible, having a conference dial or invite a sip address would be almost as good.

Obvious this is the basic sip dial from a pstn, but can't see how this could be used with the Twiml Conference verbs.
https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/sip

```
<Response>
<Dial>
    <Sip>
        sip:jack@example.com
    </Sip>
</Dial>
</Response>
```

Also I can see that the Api supports 'Create a Participant – Agent Conference only', however we don't use the Agent Conference Only conference type and we've concerned this would break existing functionality.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-participant-resource

I guess we're hoping this can be achieved with Twiml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are initiating a call out toward your SIP infrastructure (if I am understanding you correctly?), you would use the Twilio REST API Calls resource to do so, and the To: would be a SIP URI. The URL would be pointing toward TwiML which then join the SIP participant into the conference when they answer.

If you want them to dial into Twilio via SIP from your SIP infrastructure, you would set up a [SIP Domain](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/sending-sip).

You actually have an incredible amount of flexibility with either approach.

Alan

[Making Calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/make-calls)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 

Yes we have setup a sip domain

Can you point my at the documentation where we would dial Twilio via sip or provide an example also for the Rest API Call.

Yes in testing we use use Twiml to dial a sip number when using pstn.

Also we connect to the sip domain out infrastructure, again in testing.

Comment: Although not specific to your example (since it uses a registered SIP end-point to Twilio), the call flow diagram are very similar with regards a SIP Domain without registration - https://www.twilio.com/blog/registering-sip-phone-twilio-inbound-outbound. Making SIP Calls -> https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/sip-making-calls

Comment: We've done some investigation and determined that our communications infrastructure REGISTERs with the twilio domain. Then when a caller rings via pstn, twilm is used to make a sip call. This is passed to our CI and and INVITE is negotiated. Therefore our CI doesn't actually make a sip call, it only REGISTERs. Therefore the `Voice Configuration` on the sip domain is purely for sip telephones. I'm still unclear how our CI would join a twillio conference ?

Comment: Oh did you mean something like this ? `<Response><Say>Hi Sip User</Say><Dial><Sip url="https://ourdomain/Conference.ashx" method="POST">sip:jigasi@ourdomain-ote.sip.us1.twilio.com</Sip></Dial></Response>`

Comment: Can your clarify CI? Also, you can create multiple SIP Domains.

Comment: So if your Communication Infrastructure (CI) registers with a Twilio SIP Domain, then it basically is a registered SIP end-point from the Twilio perspective. Any calls you place from your CI to your Twilio SIP Domain (which you fully control based on the dial plan of your CI) hits the Voice URL of your Twilio SIP Domain. You can point your Voice URL to your own application logic (we have helper libraries for many languages or you could use Serverless Twilio Functions) that dynamically return TwiML based on dialed destination for example, so you have full control over the behavior. Help?